# In this program at the end I want to ask question for continue the program or not but it's not working properly

Tags: python, file, validation, output, continuations

[here I attached an image of my program[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS7Fq.png)

Comment: Please add the actual text of the code inside of the question, instead of a picture of it.

Comment: can't input the code there

Comment: here it is   end of the program,                                                                                                                                                          customer_file.write(last_name+','+first_name+','+join_date+','+reward_points)
print("Writing data to file customersl.txt ...")

more = input("Do you want to enter details for another customer? (y/n): ")
while(more=="y"):
    customer_file.close()
print("Closing file customersl.txt ...")
print("Goodbye")
print("-------------------------------------------------")

Comment: You have to add it into the **body** of the question.